# Fantasy novel with a boy on a quest to fulfil a prophecy in a fantasy world with flame fairies

Tags: story-identification

So, I picked up this book from the school library somewhere between Middle and High School. I feel as though, over time, I've mixed a few books together in my futile search. I'm in my mid 20's now, so It's been quite some time.

Here's what I remember. A boy or young man has to go on a quest of some sort to fulfill a prophecy or deliver something? He takes people with him, or adds people to his crew along the way. During this voyage, they have to hide inside a tree from flame fairies, or there is a fairy in the tree. Something within that jumble of misremembering.

I thought it was one of the Anne Mccaffrey books, but none of them sounded right when reading through some synopsis'.

That's honestly all I remember. I just remember it was epic and an awesome read at the time.

---

Taken from OP's comment:

> I'm [not] sure of any names within the book. I feel like he was supposed to deliver something. There was much adversity along the way. Maybe the fairies knew what he was carrying, or were trying to sabotage his mission? No love interest as far as I remember. I read it in English and it did not have pictures.

Comment: I'm willing to be there's a bunch of information you'll remember if you work through the checklists; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: What was the boy's name? What was his quest? Who was the antagonist? Was there magic in this fantasy world? Were there dragons? Why were the flame fairies trying to find them? Was there a love-interest? Was this a YA novel? Did you read this in English? Did the book have pictures in it?

Comment: It sounds more like the sort of thing Piers Anthony would have written.

Comment: I'm sure of any names within the book. I feel like he was supposed to deliver something. There was much adversity along the way. Maybe the fairies knew what he was carrying, or were trying to sabotage his mission? No love interest as far as I remember. I read it in English and it did not have pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *The Colour of Magic* by Terry Pratchett?

There is a fire and hiding in the tree and collecting people for the team.

> The story begins in Ankh-Morpork, the biggest city on the Discworld.
>   The main character is an incompetent and cynical wizard named
>   Rincewind, who is hired as a guide to the rich but naive Twoflower, an
>   insurance clerk from the Agatean Empire who has come to visit
>   Ankh-Morpork. Initially attempting to flee with his advance payment,
>   Rincewind is captured by the Patrician of Ankh-Morpork, who forces him
>   to protect Twoflower, lest the tourist's death provoke the Agatean
>   Emperor into invading Ankh-Morpork. After Twoflower is kidnapped by a
>   gang of thieves and taken to the Broken Drum Pub, Rincewind stages a
>   rescue alongside the Luggage, an indestructible, enchanted and
>   sentient chest belonging to Twoflower. Before this, Twoflower
>   convinces the Drum's barman to take out a fire insurance policy; the
>   barman subsequently attempts to burn down the Drum to claim the money,
>   but ends up causing a fire that destroys the whole of Ankh-Morpork.
>   Rincewind and Twoflower escape in the chaos.
>
> Rincewind and Twoflower travel towards the city of Quirm, unaware that
>   their adventures on this journey are actually the subject of a
>   boardgame played by the Gods of the Discworld. The pair are separated
>   when they are attacked by a mountain troll summoned by Offler the
>   Crocodile God. The ignorant Twoflower ends up being led to the Temple
>   of Bel-Shamharoth, a being said to be the opposite of both good and
>   evil, while Rincewind ends up imprisoned in a dryad-inhabited tree in
>   the woods, where he watches the events in Bel Shamharoth's temple
>   through a magical portal. The pair are reunited when Rincewind escapes
>   into the temple through the portal, and they encounter Hrun the
>   Barbarian, a parody of heroes in the Swords and Sorcery genre. The
>   trio are attacked and nearly killed by Bel-Shamharoth, but escape when
>   Rincewind accidentally blinds the creature with Twoflower's magical
>   picture box. Hrun agrees to travel with and protect Twoflower and
>   Rincewind in exchange for heroic pictures of him from the picture box.
>
> Source: Wikipedia article for [*The Colour of Magic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colour_of_Magic)